# Export all categories & products then import them

Tags: category, export, magento-1.9.2.1

I have a website with categories & products. Some of the categories & products also have images attached.

I want to:

1. Export all the categories & products.
2. Delete all the categories & products from another website.
3. Import the first exported categories & products into this new website.

Is there a fast way to do this?

P.S.2 My other websites are cloned. They have the same attributes.

P.2.3 I need to do this without any purchased tools.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through below Stack link which help you definitely.

[How to install Magmi](http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-csv-import-simple-and-configurable-magento-product)

[How to Use Magmi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409116/how-to-use-magmi-for-importing-in-magento)

[Use Magmi with Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873411/magmi-category-description-import)

[Advantages of Magmi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762526/magmi-tutorials-disadvnatages-of-magmi)

[**StackOverflow Magmi Question and Answerlist**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=magmi)

Comment: I can see in the first link how to export & import my products, so that is useful but... Is there any way to export my categories or I have to create the categories manualy & then note their ID down, and then write their ID in the CSV? Also, how do I delete all the old categories & products from a website?

Answer (score 0):

How to Export product

Go to System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles -> Export All Products. From this panel chose data transfer type(Local/remote), data format and the store. From run, profile runs the process. This will export your products into the required format.

How to import product

Go to System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles -> Import All Products. Chose the correct setting from profile wizard and the data format(like .csv). Upload the sheet and click Import all product then run profile.

How to import categories

By default, there is no way to import/export categories in Magento. You have to use free mageworks extension to do such process. Install this into your system. After installation, you can export from Mageworks->Export profiles.